# Detecting database breach

Tags: mysql, dump, intrusion-detection

I wonder about detecting database breach.

Currently, I use auditd to detect making database dump with mysqldump.

I wonder what more can I do to detect potential database breach.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Could you give us some additional information?

Answer (score 0):

The general term, not specifically for database protection,  is *"intrusion detection system"* (IDS) and the often closely related *"intrusion **prevention** system"*  (IPS).

The Wikipedia article is quite informative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system

Another closely related term is [security information and event management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_information_and_event_management) (SIEM).

---

Normally you try to detect potential database breaches in the same way you test your normal security, relatively low hanging fruit are things like a port scan. A big alert should sound when that can connect remotely to your database server.

Other low hanging fruits are systems that are not kept up-to-date with security updates and bug fixes or for example overly generous file system permissions.

Much more difficult to detect are bad applications, for example a vulnerability to SQL injection.